# Dissolve features based on attribute and a distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, line

I have a streets layers where the lines don't align. There are multiple features/rows for the same street and the lines are not connected (see picture for how they look). I want to connect these lines if they have the same name and I want to be able to specify the max distance to connect these lines. Is there a way to do this in ArcGIS?

[image: Two lines of the same street, just broken out into chunks with end points not touching]

Comment: A dissolve is *not* going to spontaneously connect dangling parts. What you want and what you ask for are different. While there is certainly a way to do this, it's probably requires significant experience and a lot of work.

Comment: Can you confirm if the shift distance is the same for all the broken lines? Let's say 20 meters to the right.